# Make a local link global /test.php -> example.com/test.php

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, local

I've been working on a spider algorithm and have been having some issues with the links.

example of how it works:

got content from -> example.com/bob/index.php?page=funny+faces

content is :

```html
<html>
<a href="../jack/index.php"> link 1 </a>
<a href="/bob_more_info"> link 2 </a>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com"> link 3 </a>
</html>
```

pass content through get links function

links function returned

> [0] = ../jack/index.php
>
> [1] = /bob_more_info
>
> [2] = http://www.youtube.com

now I need to make these links urls by what page I got them on (example.com/bob/index.php?page=funny+faces)

so

> [0] -> ../jack/index.php **into** example.com/jack/index.php
>
> [1] -> /bob_more_info **into** example.com/bob/bob_more_info
>
> [2] -> http://www.youtube.com

What I am asking for is a function that can do the conversion. This is mine, but it's not always working and is becoming a pain. If you could edit it or write me a function it would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my function currently:

```cs
//example:
//$newURL = URLfix("example.com/bob/index.php?page=funny+faces", "../jack/index.php");
function URLfix ($url, $ext)
{
    if(is_valid_url($url."/"))
    {
        $url .= "/";
    }
    $ar1 = explode("/", $url);
    if(count($ar1) == 1)
    {
        return $url."/".$ext;
    }
    $target = $ar1[count($ar1) - 1];
    if($target == "")
    {
        return $url.$ext;
    }
    if(strpos(" ".$target, "."))
    {
        $cur = "";
        for($i = 0; $i < count($ar1) - 1; $i ++)
        {
            $cur .= $ar1[$i];
        $cur .= "/";
        }
        return $cur.$ext;
    }
    return $url."/".$ext;
}
```

Comment: basically I need to turn local links into global links so

Comment: No problem, you're not the first one who has exactly that problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

use explode() to split the $url into an array delimited by /, then $bits[0] for example would contain example.com

Comment: but how about : from example.com/bob/index.php?page=funny+faces <strong>with link</strong> ../bob_more_info <strong>into</strong> example.com/bob_more_info

Answer (score 0):

A specification exists which explains step by step how to resolve a relative URI to it's base URI. It's [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

- What you call a "global link" is just the [**URI Reference**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1).
- What you call a "local link" is named [**Relative Reference**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2).

Every relative reference has a base reference it refers to. The base reference is a URI reference. You can resolve a new URI reference from any base URI reference and the relative reference. This process is called [**Relative Resolution**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2).

PHP code that does this, is available in the [`Net_URL2` <sup>**PEAR Package**</sup>](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/) it has [an example how to use this](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_URL2/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_Net_URL2__Net_URL2-0.3.1docsexample.php.html#a42) look for `->resolve()`.

Answer (score 0):

since

```
example.com/jack/index.php
```

is equivalent to:

```
example.com/bob/../jack/index.php
```

I wouldn't worry about that part.  For the url, I would remove the query string first, then pop off the last segment to get the base url:

```
list($url, $query_string = explode("?", $url);
$segments = explode("/", $url);
array_pop($segments);
$base_url = implode("/", $segments);
```

Do be sure to add some error checks.

Comment: yeah, I tried that. The only issue is with the spider algorithm, I don't want to add the same links again and again, since example.com/jack/index.php and example.com/bob/../jack/index.php are different strings and do not equal, example.com/bob/../jack/index.php would be added to the database. I need to get it into the simplest form so that doesn't happen.